# Fix for Anchors while using faux full height Columns in CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

When the Page_Load event gets called to load the page, how would I have the page load already scrolled to a particular id.  I cannot use a named anchor # because it [breaks my css](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/appendix/equalheightproblems).

I can use javascript's scrollto function but i don't know how to call javascript from the asp.net page_load event.

I have several headers, and a menu that sorts the contents within each header.  So each header has a sort menu.  When I sort say Header 2 by "Oldest" I reload the page and change the orderby stuff in my sql and repopulate the repeater under each header.  On load I would like the page to load already scrolled to Header 2.  I would normally just use #Header2 on the redirect, but I can't use the this anchor method because it breaks my code.

Is there any neat method to accomplish this?

The css issue has to do with full length columns and having a border in the gutter.  I know I can use images, but the nature of my pages would require the css to be dynamic to account for the different widths and apply the appropriate background image.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the `<body>` tag to `runat="server"` and assigning an `id="body"`.  I then added this code in the Page_Load event:

```
 if (Request.QueryString["view"] != null && Request.QueryString["view"] != "")
 {
      body.Attributes["onload"] = "scroll('" + Request.QueryString["view"] + "');";
 }
 else //Probably redundant, but I have partial postbacks
 {
      body.Attributes.Remove("onload");
 }
```

It calls this JS function:

```
function scroll(id)
{
    var a = document.getElementById(id);
    if (a != null) {
        window.scrollTo(0, a.offsetTop);
    }
}
```

So instead of using #header2, I use a querystring of view=header2 because I have to do a postback anyway.  If I just want to go to a named anchor I use onclick="scroll('header2')" in the link.